# Not able to load another tableView from another tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have designed an app that basically has a tableview has a rootView , and then three controllers(2 tableviews and 1 view controller) are intended to be loaded based upon the row clicked on the root view controller. I have added present modally segue to all the three views from the root view controller. but the views aren't getting loaded. I am not passing any data between the views. only loading the views. The code where am trying to load the views is

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    NSLog("It did enter the didselectRowAtIndexPath")
    if (indexPath.section == 0){
        func prepareForSegue(segue : UIStoryboardSegue , sender : AnyObject?) {
                segue.destinationViewController as? DetailsViewController
               NSLog("Loading Details view controller")
            }
        }


    if (indexPath.section == 1){
        func prepareForSegue(segue : UIStoryboardSegue , sender : AnyObject?) {
            segue.destinationViewController as? AppCatalogViewController
            NSLog("Loading AppCatalog view controller")
        }

    }

    if (indexPath.section == 2){
        func prepareForSegue(segue : UIStoryboardSegue , sender : AnyObject?) {
            segue.destinationViewController as? supportViewController
            NSLog("Loading support view controller")
        }
}
   }
```

Note: "It did enter the didSelectRowAtindexPath" gets printed in the log.!
can anyone guide me with what should be done ? Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

use performSegueWithIdentifier: instead of prepareForSegue, prepareForSegue is executed before a segue is performed, and it's for some setting ups for the view controller to be presented.

Comment: when i try to do this , the app crashes with the error that it has no segues named "-theseguename-" inspite of me naming the segues correctly .. before i cross check the names again , is there anything else that might generate this error ?

Comment: @ManeeshSharma where do you name the segue? and do you drag the segue from the view controller or from the table view cell?

Comment: named it in the stortyboard's attribute inspector .. and dragged it from the view controller , not from the table view cell .

Comment: Is it necessary for me to have push segue or something ?? or is there a possibility of me not doing something that might be important ?

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318224/receiver-has-no-segue-with-identifier-execption)，try to use other simulators and run again

Comment: I am running it on a live device and not on simulators and i cleaned the product , built again , but still the error persists.

Comment: what about delete the segue, recreate it, and name it different? and remember to update the segue name in your code.

Comment: another thing is that I have sender as nil .. should i set it to self ? Does it affect this in any possible way ?

Comment: sender could be nil, could be anything you want, but if you want to pass some data through the sender, you make sure you convert it to the correct type

Comment: tried doing that as well , but still the error persists.

Comment: And my rootViewController is a sub class of UITableViewController and not UIViewController .. would this create any issue ?

Comment: I don't think so，it could very possible a bug of Xcode

Comment: you sure about that ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but we have tried everything we can,  and still unlucky. If you create a new project and clone what you have done here, the problem may long gone

Comment: I have 14 swift files , some 1000's of lines of code .. and i cannot clone it and take risk of doing something very wrong

Comment: Can you find another Mac with Xcode? Run the project in that Mac to see whether the issue remains? Just to prove its a bug of your code or Xcode

Comment: i don't think @MudOnTire it's bug , i'm sure maneesh  is doing mistake somewhere. maneesh can you share screenshot of storyboard  ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]use performSegueWithIdentifier

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
NSLog("It did enter the didselectRowAtIndexPath")

  if (indexPath.section == 0){
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("IdentifierName", sender: sender)
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1){
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("IdentifierName", sender: sender)
  } else if (indexPath.section == 2){
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("IdentifierName", sender: sender)
  }
}
```

prepareForSegue define in UIViewController class and default implementation of this method does nothing. and it called for all segues.
and if you want you can override this.

Comment: sahil , when i try to do this , the app crashes with the error that it has no segues named "-theseguename-"  inspite of me naming the segues correctly .. before i cross check the names again , is there anything else that might generate this error ?

Comment: The names are same in the storyboard as well as the didSelectRowAtIndex method.

Comment: you need to segue through dragging .
this  link will clear you everything.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html

Comment: I have dragged and then connected a present modally segue , mentioned the class name as well correctly in the attributes inspector , cleaned the app , then executed, still the error persists

Comment: you need to click on the segue object then add identifier in you attributes inspector.

Comment: Yes. I did that . and to cross check that , now when i click on the segue , I can see the name being displayed in the attributes inspector.

Comment: it should be work. and can you show your updated code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108260/discussion-between-maneesh-sharma-and-sahil).

Comment: And my rootViewController is a sub class of UITableViewController and not UIViewController .. would this create any issue ?